# Can I change a key on my keyboard to be a special character?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, characters

I am trying to find a way to map keys on my keyboard to type special characters such as mu, alpha, etc. For example, I want to assign the slash on my numpad to be μ. Does anyone know a way to do this? This is in windows 8.

Comment: First of all, Welcome to Super User!  I'm sure that someone else will come along with a more thorough explanation, but the simple answer is that many people utilize [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to do that.  You can use their free software to map any Windows key to do virtually anything, including special characters.

Comment: Cheers, this looks like the way to go. I've figured out how to make hotstrings and hotkeys, but I can't use the actual symbols in the code and save it without an error popping up saying the unicode information will be lost. Thoughts?

Comment: Found this code in an AHK forum that is perfect for what I wanted, Cheers.
https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/27625-greek-letters/

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Once again, welcome to the Super User community and if you need anything else, you know where to find us.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/download/). You can read the documentation to write a script [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/frame.htm#AutoHotkey.htm). For your example, I'll explain how to write a basic script to remap a key:

1. Download and install AutoHotkey or use the portable compiler.
2. With AutoHotkey installed, right-click on any blank space on your desktop or any Windows Explorer window and go to new > AutoHotkey Script
3. Name and right click on the created file. Select Edit Script, a window should appear. The window title most likely ends in Notepad. If you did not see the Edit Script option in the context menu, open Notepad, press the file button in the top left of the window, select open, and navigate to the file. Make sure you set the type of file from "Text Documents (*.txt)" to "All Files (*.*)"
4. In the file, type or copy (Highlight the text, right-click, and select copy) and paste the text into the notepad window (right-click, and select paste)

   NumpadDiv::SendRaw μ
5. Save the file and double-click on it to run. Make sure to save the file in an encoding that supports the character, or it will not send the correct character when the button is pressed. Unicode should work in most cases.

You may notice a little H icon in the bottom right of your taskbar, this just shows that the script is running. If you want to add more keys to this, just reopen the file (step 3), make another line, and type the code under step 4. Make sure to change "NumpadDiv" to either a key on the keyboard or a special key (a list can be found [here](https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)), and the "μ" should be changed to any key or sequence of keys.